# How do I get across the water to defeat the second hanging skulltula?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm in the first temple of Skyward Sword. I've defeated the first hanging skulltula there, how do I make it across the water to reach the other one and get the treasure chest?

Comment: Can you perhaps be a little more precise as to where exactly you are?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about the Skyview Temple.  I don't quite remember what part of the temple you're asking about, so here is a [video walkthrough](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda14-skyward-sword-video-walkthrough-03.php).  Hopefully you'll find the part troubling you.  If you don't, here are [video walkthroughs for the whole game](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda14-skyward-sword-video-walkthrough.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you are at the part I am thinking of, you do not face the second skulltula yet.  Turn to your left, and there will be a crystal switch that you must hit with your slingshot.  This will cause the water level to rise, which will lead a path to the dungeon map.  Once you have the map and return to this room, that is when you will be able to face and kill the second skulltula.